# Check for Nested Table Tags Using HTMLAgilityPack C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, html-table, html-agility-pack

I need to check for nested table tags in a given string using HTMLAgilityPack.
I am using using the descendant function but it's not giving me the correct response.
Example String:

```html
<table><tr>Ye</tr><table><tr>He</tr></table><span></span></table>
```

Comment: Could you provide a valid html table code?

Comment: @qnguyen I would be getting inputs inthis form only.

Comment: So, you want to get content in nested table: <tr>He</tr>?

Comment: @qnguyen I just want to check if a table tag contains another table tag within it. I was hoping the getDescendants function would help but it did not pick up the table tag